# Thread pools and context switching slowdowns

Tags: c++, multithreading, switch-statement

I have a thread pool with idling threads that wait for jobs to be pushed to a queue, in a windows application.

I have a loop in my main application thread that adds 1000 jobs to the pool's queue sequentially (it adds a job, then waits for the job to finish, then adds another job, x1000). So no actual parallel processing is happening...here's some pseudocode:

```
////threadpool:
class ThreadPool
{
    ....

    std::condition_variable job_cv;
    std::condition_variable finished_cv;
    std::mutex job_mutex;
    std::queue<std::function <void(void)>> job_queue;

    void addJob(std::function <void(void)> jobfn)
    {
        std::unique_lock <std::mutex> lock(job_mutex);
        job_queue.emplace(std::move(jobfn));
        job_cv.notify_one();
    }

    void waitForJobToFinish()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(job_mutex);
        finished_cv.wait(lock, [this]() {return job_queue.empty(); });
    }

    ....

    void threadFunction() //called by each thread when it's first started
    {
        std::function <void(void)> job;
        while (true)
        {
            std::unique_lock <std::mutex> latch(job_mutex);
            job_cv.wait(latch, [this](){return !job_queue.empty();});

            {
                job = std::move(job_queue.front());
                job_queue.pop();

                latch.unlock();

                job();

                latch.lock();
                finished_cv.notify_one();
            }      
        }
    }
}
```

...

```
////main application:

void jobfn()
{
    //do some lightweight calculation
}

void main()
{
    //test 1000 calls to the lightweight jobfn from the thread pool
    for (int q = 0; q < 1000; q++)
    {        
        threadPool->addJob(&jobfn);
        threadPool->waitForJobToFinish(); 
    }
}
```

So basically what's happening is a job is added to the queue and the main loop begins to wait, a waiting thread then picks it up, and when the thread finishes, it notifies the application that the main loop can continue and another job can be added to the queue, etc. So that way 1000 jobs are processed sequentially.

It's worth noting that the jobs themselves are tiny and can complete in a few milliseconds.

However, I've noticed something strange....

The time it takes for the loop to complete is essentially O(n) where n is the number of threads in the thread pool. So even though jobs are processed one-at-a-time in all scenarios, a 10-thread pool takes 10x longer to complete the full 1000-job task than a 1-thread pool.

I'm trying to figure out why, and my only guess so far is that context switching is the bottleneck...maybe less (or zero?) context switching overhead is required when only 1 thread is grabbing jobs...but when 10 threads are continually taking their turn to process a single job at a time, there's some extra processing required? But that doesn't make sense to me...wouldn't it be the same operation required to unlock thread A for a job, as it would be thread B,C,D...? Is there some OS-level caching going on, where a thread doesn't lose context until a different thread is given it? So calling on the same thread over and over is faster than calling threads A,B,C sequentially?

But that's a complete guess at this point...maybe someone else could shed some insight on why I'm getting these results...Intuitively I assumed that so long as only 1 thread is executing at a time, I could have a thread pool with an arbitrarily large number of threads and the total task completion time for [x] jobs would be the same (so long as each job is identical and the total number of jobs is the same)...why is that wrong?

Comment: This may not be related, but how many cores do you have?

Comment: @merlin2011 16 (2 CPU x 8 cores).

Comment: Also, how are you benchmarking this? That is, are you measuring time at the start and end, or collecting data on each task so you can tell whether it's 1 in every 10 that is super slow?

Comment: @merlin2011 I'm measuring at the start and end only...the tasks themselves complete extremely quickly so I'm not sure how accurate individual task measurements would be...although I didn't think about whether the slowdowns are maybe only occurring at certain frequencies...

Comment: This is pure speculation (since I can't benchmark your code without a complete example), but it could be that you're occasionally crossing socket boundaries when you have larger number of threads, which would show up as an expensive job every few seconds. If you want to measure individual tasks accurately and you're on Intel, you can use the `rdtsc` instruction. You can grab a convenient wrapper from [this library](https://github.com/PlatformLab/PerfUtils/blob/master/src/Cycles.cc).

Comment: Full disclosure, this code is from my research, but here's an [example](https://github.com/PlatformLab/ArachnePerfTests/blob/master/src/ArachneYieldTest.cc) where we measure latencies on the order of ten's of nanoseconds.

Comment: @merlin2011 Thanks for that, I'll look into it!

Comment: Your "thread" pool as posted has no more than one job running at all times, that is, you have a 1-thread pool, a.k.a. sequential processing. There are no threads other than the main thread at all. You claim that processing jobs in some other manner is slower, or no faster, but there's no code to demonstrate that, and you are not saying how you are measuring time. Please *show* (don't *tell*) what you have done to come up with your conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

Your "guess" is correct; it's simply a resource contention issue.

Your 10 threads are not idle, they're waiting. This means that the OS has to iterate over the currently active threads for your application, which means a context switch likely occurs.

The active thread is pushed back, a "waiting" thread pulled to the front, in which the code checks if the signal has been notified and the lock can be acquired, since it likely can't in the time slice for that thread, it continues to iterate over the remaining threads, each trying to see if the lock can be acquired, which it can't because your "active" thread hasn't been allotted a time slice to complete yet.

A single-thread pool doesn't have this issue because no additional threads need to be iterated over at the OS level; granted, a single-thread pool is still slower than just calling `job` 1000 times.

Hope that can help.